# Finding all distinct primes $p$ and $q$ such that $pq^3 + p^3q$ has exactly 12 divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> How do you find all possible distinct prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $pq^3 + p^3q$ has exactly $12$ divisors?

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if factoring into $pq(q^2+p^2)$ does anything, but I am lost on this.

Comment: $pq(q^2 + p^2)$ at least tells you that $(q^2 + p^2)$ must have $3$ divisors.  See why?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think you mean 3 divisors.

Comment: Number of divisors function $d(n)$ is multiplicative so $d(ab)=d(a)d(b)$ whenever $a,b$ are coprime. Here $pq$ and $p^2+q^2$ are coprime (can you see why?), and so $12=d(pq(p^2+q^2))=d(pq)d(p^2+q^2)=4d(p^2+q^2)$, i.e. $d(p^2+q^2)=3$.

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then the three factors in the factorization
$$pq^3+p^3q=pq(p^2+q^2),$$
are pairwise coprime. It follows that if the number of divisors of each factor is $a$, $b$ and $c$, respectively, then the product has $a\times b\times c$ factors. Of course $a=b=2$ because $p$ and $q$ are prime, so to get $abc=12$ we must have $c=3$. It follows that
$$p^2+q^2=r^2,$$
for some prime number $r$. Reducing mod $2$ shows that either $p$ or $q$ is divisible by $2$, and reducing mod $3$ shows that either $p$ or $q$ is divisible by $3$. Then
$$r^2=p^2+q^2=2^2+3^2=13,$$
a contradiction. Hence no solution exists.

Comment: Reducing $\mod 2$ first sounds good, at least I can go to sleep now :).

Answer (score 2):

No solution.

As already indicated by David Stork's comment, since
$pq$ will have 4 divisors, $p^2 + q^2$ must have 3 divisors.  This means that
you must have a pythagorean triplet $p^2 + q^2 = P^2$, where $P$ is a prime.

Researching https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple,
you can assume WLOG that $q = 2.$

This means that $P^2 - 4 = p^2 \implies (P-2)(P+2) = p^2.$

Since $p$ must be odd, $p$ can't divide $2$.
This means that $p$ can't divide both $(P-2)$ and $(P+2).$ 
This means that $P-2 = 1.$
That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For $p,q$ distinct primes, $pq$ always has exactly $4$ divisors. It must be that
$q^2+p^2$ has $3$ divisors which means that $q^2+p^2 = x^2 \equiv 0,1 \mod 3$ and working in $\mod 3$ we see that there is no solution when $p,q \neq 3$. If $p=3$ then we only have solutions for $9+q^2 = x^2$ with composite $q$.